# Suzuki SD 110 cc

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, fuel-filter, fuel-leak

bike almost 9 years old, replaced carburetor once so it is 5 years working perfect. few days ago i changed gas filter because it was looking too sluggy. (petrol filter that not actually installed by company so i put a filter myself to protect it from dust etc, that lasted for about 1 year).

after a month use, filter is still clean with no clog but bike has started the problem of OVER FLOW from drain pipe of carburetor which never stops until i disconnect the main supply pipe from tank and let bike started for few minutes until all remaining gas is burnt in the chamber. then i reconnect the pipe and it again start works and the problem come back within 4 or 5 days again, or may be early.
The filter still looks now and clear. gas can be seen flowing throw it. can it be problem with filter or the CARBURETOR has ended its life.

Comment: Is the limit valve wedged open in the carburetor?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest this is a carb float issue, not a problem with your filter. If the float isn't floating, you'll overfill the fuel bowls.